# Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o Banco de Dados

Tags: php, wordpress, script, wordpress-theme

Estou recebendo várias vezes essa mensagem :

Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o Banco de Dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Li algumas matérias sobre esse problema e sempre a solução que indicam é verificar o arquivo WP-config  e verificar se o nome de usuario e senha do MYsql estão corretos, e estão corretos.

Existe alguma outra maneira de verifica o que pode está sobrecarregando o Mysql?

No meu tema no arquivo index.php, adicionei o codigo abaixo:

```
   <?php echo catch_that_image(25, 14) ?>
```

e no arquivo Function.php esse outro:

```
function catch_that_image($w, $h) {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
$new_img_tag = "";

ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image with 0 width
    $new_img_tag = "<img src='/images/noimage.jpg' width='0px' class='' />";
}

else{
    $new_img_tag = '<img alt=" - ' . $post->post_title . ' - " title="' . $post->post_title . '" src="' . $first_img . '" width="' . $w . '" height="' . $h . '" class="" />';
}

return $new_img_tag;
}
```

Esse codigo é para chamar imagens hospedadas fora do wordpress e mostra-las no tema.

Esse codigo pode está relacionado ao erro de Mysql?

Comment: Verifique se o usuário e senha do mysql estão corretos.

Comment: Já verifiquei e estão corretos

Comment: Você poderia colar o erro e o código de conexão no post?

Comment: Editei a pergunta olha lá

Comment: Anexei uma imagem com erro

Comment: Verifique se o servidor MySQL está  ativo e ligado, por exemplo usando o `service mysqld status`, se tiver acesso ao SSH do servidor do MySQL ou utilize `mysql -h 111.222.333.444 -p -u Usuario DB`

Comment: estão hospedados na mesma hospedagem?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é um problema muito simples de ser resolvido.

Tá dando erro, mas porque? É claro que existe um problema na conexão, então, a princípio, pode ser os dados de login ou a permissão de acesso.

O banco está localizado no mesmo servidor onde os arquivos do WP estão? Se estiver em outro servidor, lembre-se que é necessário liberar acesso remoto e no firewall (se houver).

Crie um arquivo .php com o código abaixo e altere as informações de conexão informando os dados corretos.

```
<?php

$host = ''; //Se o banco de dados estiver no mesmo servidor deste arquivo, use localhost
$database = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database};charset={$charset}",
        $user, $password);
    echo 'Conexão feita com sucesso.';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<h1>Falha na conexão com o banco de dados</h1>'
        .'<hr>'
        .'<pre>';
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Se der erro, ele irá exibir o motivo do erro, basta ler a saída que será imprimida na tela.

Detalhe: o charset é `utf8` mesmo, sem hífen.

Se os dados estão corretos, as permissões de acesso estão corretas e não existe erros no código de conexão, então o que resta é: o MySQL não está rodando ou está mal configurado.

Comment: Se isto der solução ao problema, sugiro renomear a pergunta para *"Como debugar uma conexão MySQL"*